# .NET 6 Console App vs. Web API for large background jobs

Tags: .net, azure-blob-storage, asp.net-core-webapi, console-application, .net-6.0

I need to migrate hundreds of thousands of records containing large text columns from a SQL Server database to Azure Blob Storage.

Obviously optimization is a concern.  I do not want this program running for days on end if it can be avoided.

Off the top of my head I would think a web based application (i.e. a .NET 6 Core Web API) project would run much slower than a Console App running in the background so I started building a Console App for this task.  However, I'm finding DI issues with the Console App frustrating and therefore I am tempted to do this as a Core Web API and be done with it.

If I do in fact use a .NET 6 Core Web API as my project, would you expect the task to run exponentially slower?

Comment: _“would you expect the task to run exponentially slower”_ — why should this _ever_ be the case? No.

Comment: Have you considered azure data factory?

Comment: you can think of worker service

Comment: api is not the way to go; if you do web api your request will eventually timeout you will have to have postman waiting for the result otherwise request will potentially get cancelled; if you try force your code on startup web server will kill your api app after certain time; write it as console app; all DI features can be used in console app almost the same way as in web api; implement a resume feature as it will get stopped at some point so you want it to not restart; deploy it somwhere close to the database or the blob storage - do not run it from your local :).

Comment: Thank you @Rafal.  I did in fact get the console app working and have successfully sent records to blob storage.  I'm curious why you would say do not run if from my local? If I run it Azure I need a resource on which to deploy it (and probably its own repo) and have a feeling my manager will not like that.

Comment: It was due to latency, if you have your local station far away from database and azure data center it will take longer to execute, and from what you have written, it sounded as it was a lot of data. The difference in count of timeouts and execution time is significant. I cannot speak to your managers :) but the bigger the company the less the cost of such things matters.